# Community user posting comments?

Tags: support, comments, community-user, first-answers, first-questions

I just saw a comment posted by the [*Community* user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

> Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Here's a screenshot of the comment, in case it disappears:

[image]

The comment was posted on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68995242/1974224.

Is there a feature (maybe involving [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)) that posts such comments?

Comment: From [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/348196): _"Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will appear as a comment from the Community account"_

Comment: "in case it disappears".. that's not going to happen, because [no one can remove it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369231/918208) :D

Comment: *involving Machine Learning* nope, the feature is pretty *stoopid* and stays that way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This behaviour was announced on Stack Exchange: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release). When users are doing certain review options, they are asked to comment, but they also can choose to remain anonymous and the [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) User will comment for them based on their selection.

For the First Post queue they would get the following options, which would result in the [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) User posting a comment:

> #### Changes to the First posts queue
>
> ##### First posts → First questions AND First answers queue
>
> - Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will appear as a comment from the Community account.
>   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh1hB.png]
>   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtPQC.jpg]

As far as I can tell from the linked announcement, this is the only queue this occurs in (though that doesn't mean to say it isn't and it's just not explicitly specified it happens in other queues).

Comment: Is this only for the first questions/answers review queues? Or is it for all review queues?

Comment: The above is the only place that mentions that the community user would do so, @Sabito錆兎 , so I would *assume* so.

Comment: Do these comments get auto-deleted if the user does nothing about the problems? I ran into a low-quality question earlier that someone upvoted. Now there are two comments on it including the community one. Wouldn't that mean the roomba will ignore this post a year from now if nobody else downvotes it past 0?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance there's no time-based auto-deletion for comments. Just like with expired flags to possible duplicate closure, the comment is still there.

Comment: That isn't what they are asking about, @AndrewT. That ask asking about the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) rules on the *question* not the comments.

Comment: @ThomA well, yeah, the question won't be roomba'd because the comments won't get auto-deleted by the system either.